# Oracle: SQL query that returns rows with only numeric values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field (column in Oracle) called X that has values like "a1b2c3", "abc", "1ab", "123", "156"

how do I write an sql query that returns me only the X that hold pure numerical values = no letters?  from the example above would be „123“ and „156“

select X
from myTable
where ...??

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the `REGEXP_LIKE` function as:

```
SELECT X 
FROM myTable 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Sample run:

```
SQL> SELECT X FROM SO;

X
--------------------
12c
123
abc
a12

SQL> SELECT X  FROM SO WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$');

X
--------------------
123

SQL>
```

Comment: You can use regexp in Oracle 10i as well

Comment: @andr: Thanks :) I tried it on a 11g box, so was not sure when did Oracle introduce regex.

Comment: This test have the advantage of stripping the null values compared to LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(string1, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))).

Comment: Does this still work? We have a 12c database yet this doesn't seem to work to only select rows that give back numbers for a column.

Answer (score 38):

If the only characters to consider are **letters** then you can do:

```
select X from myTable where upper(X) = lower(X)
```

But of course that won't filter out other characters, just letters.

Since Oracle 12c (at least) there has been a built-in function to check whether a character value is numeric: [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

```
select X from myTable where validate_conversion(X as number) = 1
```

Comment: Note that this solution is much faster than regexp or function approach: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1132906300346063525

Answer (score 8):

If you use Oracle 10 or higher you can use regexp functions as codaddict suggested. In earlier versions `translate` function will help you:

```
select * from tablename  where translate(x, '.1234567890', '.') is null;
```

More info about Oracle translate function can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) or in official documentation "SQL Reference"

**UPD:** If you have signs or spaces in your numbers you can add "`+-`" characters to the second parameter of `translate` function.

Comment: If you String-Dates in your column like `2019-05-15` (in case you added +-) or `25.25.219` or other numbers with multiple dots in them like formatted Customer numbers `201.20111.56`, IP-Addresses `192.168.1.1`, etc., they will be in your result. You cannot automatically assume that a `to_number` function will succeed.

Answer (score 5):

What about 1.1E10, +1, -0, etc?  Parsing all possible numbers is trickier than many people think.  If you want to include as many numbers are possible you should use the to_number function in a PL/SQL function.  From http://www.oracle-developer.net/content/utilities/is_number.sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_number (str_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
   n NUMBER;
BEGIN
   n := TO_NUMBER(str_in);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Comment: This addresses a different question.  He didn't say numbers, he said digits.

Comment: I interpreted "numeric values" to mean "number".  I was thinking of the context of converting strings to numbers; a situation where you really need to use PL/SQL to prevent out-of-order execution causing "invalid number" errors.  If he really just want to check digits, then you're right, this won't work.

Answer (score 4):

The complete list of the regexp_like and other regexp functions in Oracle 11.1:

http://66.221.222.85/reference/regexp.html

In your example:

```
SELECT X
FROM test
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]$');
```

Comment: This will not work, it'll report rows that have a digit anywhere. You need to use anchors.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm has some useful info

Answer (score 3):

You can use following command -

```
LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(string1, '+-.0123456789', '')))
```

This will return NULL if your `string1` is Numeric

your query would be -

```
select * from tablename 
where LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(X, '+-.0123456789', ''))) is null
```

Comment: Cite from official SQL Reference documentation: "You cannot use an empty string for to_string to remove all characters in from_
string from the return value". So you can't use empty string as the third argument in TRANSLATE(string1, '+-.0123456789', '')

Comment: I think the third argument needs to be a space: ' '