# Checking if the value inserted is a Varchar or an Integer

Tags: sql, oracle, integer

I'm using SQL Developer/Oracle and I need to check in a trigger if the the value inserted on a specific field is an integer or just a "string".

I tried `isnumeric()`, but this function doesn't exist in Oracle. What's the equivalent in Oracle since I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666986/how-can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-sql

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if the column is numeric or varchar datatype or whether the contents of a varchar column can be converted to a number?

Comment: I'm using an if. This means if the value inserted is varhchar I will raise an application error, otherwise I will do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last comment to the [@Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020910/997660)

> '1234' should be considered as a string and fail

it seems like you want to do a *data type* checking of a literal upon insertion and allow to insert only literals of numeric data types. Oracle does an implicit data type conversion when it makes sense. For example, you have a column of number data type in your table. When you try to insert a character literal `'123'` to that column, the operation will succeed despite the fact that the literal is of character data type(`char`, simple character literals are of `CHAR` data type not `varchar2` by default), because Oracle *takes a look* at the data type of a column, then at data type and elements of the character literal and decides 'Yes, it makes sense to convert that character literal to a number.' and does it. As @Ben said , it probably would be better to let your application do the checking whether a value you are trying to insert into a table is of number or character data type.

Having said that, the probably simplest method to do a data type checking and allow to insert only literals or variables of numeric data types would be creating a package with one overloading function, say `isnumber()`. First version of the function has a formal parameter of `varchar2` data type and its overloaded version has formal parameter of `number` data type. Depending on a data type of actual parameter Oracle will choose appropriate version of the function:

```
SQL> create or replace package Util1 as
  2    function isnumber(p_val in varchar2)
  3      return varchar2;
  4    function isnumber(p_val in number)
  5      return number;
  6  end;
  7  /
Package created

SQL> create or replace package body Util1 as
  2    function isnumber(p_val in varchar2)
  3      return varchar2 is
  4    begin
  5      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not a numeric data type');
  6    end;
  7  
  8    function isnumber(p_val in number)
  9       return number is
 10    begin
 11      return p_val;
 12    end;
 13  end;
 14  /
Package body created
```

When you call `util1.isnumber()` function with actual parameter of numeric data type it simply returns it back, and when the function is called with an actual parameter   of a character data type exception will be raised.

```
SQL> create table t1(col number);
Table created

SQL> insert into t1(col) values(util1.isnumber(123));
1 row inserted

SQL> commit;
Commit complete

SQL> insert into t1(col) values(util1.isnumber('123'));

ORA-20000: Not a numeric data type
ORA-06512: at "HR.UTIL1", line 5

SQL> insert into t1(col) values(util1.isnumber('12345f'));

ORA-20000: Not a numeric data type
ORA-06512: at "HR.UTIL1", line 5
```

**Note** This approach wont work in a trigger because of implicit data type conversion. In trigger you would have to do the following:

```
 :new.col_name := util1.isnumber(:new.col_name)
```

As `col_name` is of `number` data type, Oracle will always call version of `isnumber()` function with formal parameter of number data type and insert will succeed even if actual value being inserted is (say) `'123'`.

Comment: That's quite a clever approach; I like it!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using an if. This means if the value inserted is varhchar I will raise an application error, otherwise I will do nothing.

When you insert a character into a numeric field you'll get an "invalid number" exception raised ([ORA-01722](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722)). This makes your choice easier; *don't* test to see if the string you're inserting is a character. Capture the raised exception when a user inserts a character into a numeric field and re-raise as an application error (if you really feel you have to).

There's then no need to test at all.

For example:

```
create table test ( a number );

begin
   insert into test values ('a');
exception when INVALID_NUMBER then
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'The number wasn''t a number');
end;
/
```

It's worth noting that you could also test if something's a number in your application code (if it's an application). You wouldn't have to do the round trip to the database then.

Comment: I really need to re_raise since this is for a college project and my teacher will do everything that is in his power in order to crash my code. So if i have custom exceptions I can show him I considered every possibility, you see?

Comment: That's a "business decision" @André; personally I'm not usually in favour of obscuring the error in the database. It's better if the application catches the exception and decides what to do with it because a layer of obfuscation is removed.

Comment: There is a small catch here - implicit data type conversion. OP needs to define integer and string. Yes, if a column is of (say) number data type and you are inserting a non numeric character then yes, error `ORA-01722` will be raised. But, when the column is of number data type and you are trying to insert `'1233'` (still a character literal, not a number) implicit data type conversion will take place.

Comment: Is there a situation where Oracle _won't_ implicitly convert @Nicholas? If it's a valid number then, as far as I know, [it always will](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20808).

Comment: Right. But I was talking about how OP defines integer and string. Is '123' a string or a number(it's not a pure number now, but it will be after it implicitly converted), and should `insert` succeed in this situation or fail? Yes, 'a' not a numeric value and insert should fail. `123` is obviously a number, and `insert` should succeed. Now, how OP will define '1234'? Should it be treated as a number and succeed or should it be treated as a string and fail?

Comment: '1234' should be considered as a string and fail.