# PL SQL replace conditionally suggestion

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace the entire word with 0 if the word has any non-digit character. For example, if digital_word='22B4' then replace with 0, else if digital_word='224' then do not replace.

```
SELECT replace_funtion(digital_word,'has non numeric character pattern',0,digital_word)
FROM dual;
```

I tried decode, regexp_instr, regexp_replace but could not come up with the right solution.
Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need a function (PL/SQL) for this? You don't!

Answer (score 2):

the idea is simple - you need check if the value is numeric or not

script:

```
with nums as
(
select '123' as num from dual union all
select '456' as num from dual union all
select '7A9' as num from dual union all
select '098' as num from dual 
)
select n.* 
 ,nvl2(LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(num, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))),'0',num)
from nums n
```

result

```
1   123 123
2   456 456
3   7A9 0
4   098 098
```

see more articles below to see which way is better to you

[How can I determine if a string is numeric in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666986/how-can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-sql)

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15321803936685

[How to tell if a value is not numeric in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819709/how-to-tell-if-a-value-is-not-numeric-in-oracle)

Comment: The OP talks about "non-digit" - so if an input has the character + or . then it is "non-digits", regardless of how they could be used to represent "numbers".

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(digital_word, '\D') THEN '0' ELSE digital_word END
  FROM dual;
```

The regular expression class `\D` matches any non-digit character. You could also use `[^0-9]` to the same effect:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(digital_word, '\D') THEN '0' ELSE digital_word END
  FROM dual;
```

Alternately you could see if the value of `digital_word` is made up of nothing but digits:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(digital_word, '^\d+$') THEN digital_word ELSE '0' END
  FROM dual;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to replace all digits with null (to simply delete them) and see if anything is left. You don't need regular expressions (**slow!**) for this, you just need the standard string function `TRANSLATE()`.

Unfortunately, Oracle has to work around their own inconsistent treatment of `NULL` - sometimes as empty string, sometimes not. In the case of the `TRANSLATE()` function, you can't simply translate every digit to nothing; you must also translate a non-digit character to itself, so that the third argument is not an empty string (which **is** treated as a real `NULL`, as in relational theory). See the Oracle documentation for the `TRANSLATE()` function. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145

Then, the result can be obtained with a `CASE` expression (or various forms of `NULL` handling functions; I prefer `CASE`, which is SQL Standard):

```
with 
     nums ( num ) as (
       select '123' from dual union all
       select '-56' from dual union all
       select '7A9' from dual union all
       select '0.9' from dual 
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your own table and column names.
select num,
       case when translate(num, 'z0123456789', 'z') is null 
            then num
            else '0'
       end as result
from   nums
;

NUM  RESULT
---  ------
123  123
-56  0
7A9  0
0.9  0
```

Note: everything here is in `varchar2` data type (or some other kind of string data type). If the results should be converted to number, wrap the entire case expression within `TO_NUMBER()`. Note also that the strings `'-56'` and `'0.9'` are not all-digits (they contain non-digits), so the result is `'0'` for both. If this is not what you needed, you must correct the problem statement in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following update query will help you:

```
update [table] set [col] = '0'
where REGEXP_LIKE([col], '.*\D.*', 'i')
```

Comment: Who said anything about `update`? Why do you need the `.*` in the regular expression? Why do you need case-insensitive comparison?