# ORA-01722: Invalid number for Fr Locale for Oracle 11g

Tags: database, string, oracle, oracle11g, average

I have a view named My_View which contains one varchar column having numeric decimal data. 
While,select calculating avg in am getting error

> ORA-01722: Invalid number for Fr Locale

Here is my oracle query which i tried but getting the error:

```
select (AVG(MY_COLUMN)) 
from  MY_TABLE;

select TO_NUMBER((AVG(MY_COLUMN)), '90.9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') 
from  MY_TABLE
GROUP BY MY_COLUMN;
```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: *:one varchar column having numeric decimal data"* Presumably you know this is bad design. Anyway it sounds like you have some data into your data which contains values that cannot be cast to numbers. Perhaps you could use something like this [`is_number()` user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19572759/146325) in a WHERE clause so your view only selects values which can be converted. (In 12c R2 Oracle provide a built-in VALIDATE_CONVERSATION() which does this.)

Comment: @APC: Did you mean `VALIDATE_CONVERSION`? (And thanks - I'm glad I'm not the only one... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be in data that isn't "numeric" (why do you keep numbers in `VARCHAR2` columns)? For example, it contains '123A56'. What is `AVG` of that value?

A simple option is to use `REGEXP_LIKE` and perform numeric operations only on "valid" values. For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234.56' from dual union all  -- valid
  3     select '131'     from dual union all  -- valid
  4     select 'ABC'     from dual union all  -- invalid
  5     select 'xy.23'   from dual union all  -- invalid
  6     select '.3598'   from dual union all  -- invalid
  7     select '12.34.56'from dual            -- invalid
  8    )
  9  select col,
 10         to_number(col, '9999D9999', 'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''') col_as_num
 11  from test
 12  where regexp_like(col, '^\d+\.?\d+$');

COL      COL_AS_NUM
-------- ----------
1234.56     1234,56
131             131

SQL>
```

Now you can `AVG` such values:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234.56' from dual union all  -- valid
  3     select '131'     from dual union all  -- valid
  4     select 'ABC'     from dual union all  -- invalid
  5     select 'xy.23'   from dual union all  -- invalid
  6     select '.3598'   from dual union all  -- invalid
  7     select '12.34.56'from dual            -- invalid
  8    )
  9  select avg(to_number(col, '9999D9999', 'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''')) result
 10  from test
 11  where regexp_like(col, '^\d+\.?\d+$');

    RESULT
----------
    682,78

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works fine, but my varchar2 columns contain numeric decimal values when I divide them by 100, getting Invalid number issues again. `select mycolumn/100 from mytable;`

Comment: You're welcome. As of the problem you have: see whether REPLACE helps. Replace all decimal "comma" characters to "period" (i.e. instead of `12,45` you'll have `12.45`), and then try again. Or, if it is not about those characters, see which ones you really have. Basically, such problems iswhat you can expect when storing numbers into VARCHAR2 columns. Try not to do that.

Comment: Littlefoot Thanks for your feedback. we have fixed view on UAT and its working fine. But on production its not working. both UAT and production hosted in FR locale where we are getting this error.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way out of it. One option is to use a **loop** and apply the above code to each row separately. Doing so, you'd be able to log & skip values that have failed (and deal with them later, manually).

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Oracle 12.2, you can use the `on conversion error` clause of `to_number()` to return a default value when the conversion fails. This is handy for your use case: you can return `null` on conversion error, which aggregate function `avg()` will happily ignore.

```
select avg(
    to_number(
        my_column default null on conversion error, 
        '9999d9999', 
        'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,'''
    )
) my_avg
from my_table;
```

Comment: I wonder what made them stick to this verbose "magic" syntax instead of some optional fourth "ifConversionErrror" paramter.