# finding if a string contains number using regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I want to find if a string is a pure string using regexp_replace only.
If it is not a pure string, then designate the string as XX;
Else, use the string.

For eg:
If a string is 'A1', then since there is a number, it is not a pure string and the outout would be XX.
If the string is AB, there is no number or anything other than an aplha, then use AB.

Note: This needs to be done in a wierd requirement only with regexp_replace.
I know how this is done using regexp_like or translate etc. But, i would like to do it with regexp_replace only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if "it's a number" function in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082176/check-if-its-a-number-function-in-oracle)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate as I want the solution using only regexp_replace and the question was framed as such. The one you pointed to contains lots of solutions, but none with regexp_replace.

Comment: It contains a solution with regexp_replace; the second one down....

Comment: I still don't see it from that link ! I see solutions using regexp_instr,regexp_like and the traditional oracle builtin functions such as translate or a custom function, but not regexp_replace. I did a search for the keyword in that page and did not find any. Am I missing something that you are able to view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. With some R&D, I was able to find the solution which works as well.

```
select case when length('A1') = length(trim(regexp_replace('A1','[[:digit:]]',' '))) then 'string'
else 'alphanumeric'
end from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Oracle regexp_replace method but a 'generic' regular expression would be:
regex = `[a-z][A-Z] // Only alphabetical characters , upper case or lower case`

Answer (score -1):

```
create table regexp_replace_example(test_string varchar2(100) not null);

insert into regexp_replace_example(test_string) values ('A1');
insert into regexp_replace_example(test_string) values ('AB');

select test_string, case 
when regexp_replace(test_string,'[^a-zA-Z]') != test_string then 'XX' 
else test_string 
end as output_value
from regexp_replace_example;

drop table regexp_replace_example;
```