# How can you tell if a value is not numeric in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, isnumeric

I have the following code that returns an error message if my value is invalid.  I would like to give the same error message if the value given is not numeric.

```
IF(option_id = 0021) THEN 
      IF((value<10000) or (value>7200000) or /* Numeric Check */)THEN
          ip_msg(6214,option_name);  -- Error Message
          return;
      END IF;
END IF;
```

In SQL Server, I simply used `ISNUMERIC()`.  I would like to do something similar in Oracle. Such as,

```
IF((!ISNUMERIC(value)) or (value<10000) or (value>7200000))
    THEN ...
```

Comment: I think you should mark the `VALIDATE_CONVERSION()` answer from @LukaszSzozda
 as correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886915/5576771. Related: [Idea: IsNumeric() function](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/idea-isnumeric-function-5577).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

returns TRUE if column holds only numeric characters

Comment: Of course, not all numbers would be composed entirely of numeric characters.  "1.2" is numeric but it contains a period (or a comma depending on your NLS settings).  "-100" is numeric but it contains a minus sign.  "1.2.3" is not numeric though it is composed entirely of digits and periods.  The `regexp_like` may be sufficient if you're really looking to see whether the column holds positive integers with no formatting.

Comment: `123e-5` is also a number.

Comment: This regex would cover only positive integer values!

Comment: Use it as: `SELECT column_with_int_and_string FROM MyTable WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column_with_int_and_string, ‘^[[:digit:]]+$’);`

Comment: This regex can be expanded as necessary if more than just numeric digits is required, but I think this answer satisfies the OP and is a great start for anyone with a similar issue. Here's an example to get people going with a little more complex regex that should cover all integers (untested): `'^[+-]?[[:digit:]]+$'`

Comment: Use this for decimal numbers:  REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN, '^-?[[:digit:].]*$')

Answer (score 51):

From `Oracle DB 12c Release 2` you could use **[VALIDATE_CONVERSION](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.htm#SQLRF-GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)** function:

> VALIDATE_CONVERSION determines whether expr can be converted to the specified data type. If expr can be successfully converted, then this function returns 1; otherwise, this function returns 0. If expr evaluates to null, then this function returns 1. If an error occurs while evaluating expr, then this function returns the error.

```
 IF (VALIDATE_CONVERSION(value AS NUMBER) = 1) THEN
     ...
 END IF;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=265cb8e8224f641643c6fa9b3f60de21)**

Comment: @MarvinM Great to hear that. Please also check [DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886745/5070879)

Comment: I can't understand why this function return 1 if the value is null. It should be 0

Comment: @Salman It was defined that way probably because `SELECT CAST(null AS <datatype>) c FROM dual;` is a valid cast.

Comment: `VALIDATE_CONVERSION('' AS NUMBER)` - it says `1` - same goes for `IS_NUMERIC('')`...

Comment: If the string to check does not have decimals, this works: `CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER('') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` - why "`NULL`" or an empty string is valid/1? - doesn't make sense to me, tbh...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes `''` <=> NULL in Oracle and NULL is perfectly valid value for number.  `SELECT TO_NUMBER(NULL)`. If you create table `CREATE TABLE t(i INT)` you could insert `INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL)` without any issue and the data type of column is still number.

Answer (score 20):

There is no built-in function.  You could write one

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_numeric( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_num := to_number( p_str );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN value_error
  THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

and/or

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_to_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_num := to_number( p_str );
  RETURN l_num;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN value_error
  THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

You can then do

```
IF( is_numeric( str ) = 1 AND 
    my_to_number( str ) >= 1000 AND
    my_to_number( str ) <= 7000 )
```

If you happen to be using Oracle 12.2 or later, there are enhancements to the `to_number` function that you could leverage

```
IF( to_number( str default null on conversion error ) >= 1000 AND
    to_number( str default null on conversion error ) <= 7000 )
```

Comment: I think you want `is_numeric( str ) = 0` above if I understand the OP correctly (equivalent of `!ISNUMERIC(value)`).

Comment: @DavidFaber - I assume that is a typo.  If a string is not numeric, it wouldn't make sense to then compare it against numeric values.

Comment: Oh I see, you're using AND where the OP has OR. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 13):

The best answer I found on internet:

```
SELECT case when trim(TRANSLATE(col1, '0123456789-,.', ' ')) is null
            then 'numeric'
            else 'alpha'
       end
FROM tab1;
```

Comment: This is not suitable in scenarios where you are trying to prevent spaces before, after, or even between the digits.

Comment: look at this https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following regular expression which will match integers (e.g., `123`), floating-point numbers (`12.3`), and numbers with exponents (`1.2e3`):

```
^-?\d*\.?\d+([eE]-?\d+)?$
```

If you want to accept `+` signs as well as `-` signs (as Oracle does with `TO_NUMBER()`), you can change each occurrence of `-` above to `[+-]`. So you might rewrite your block of code above as follows:

```
IF (option_id = 0021) THEN 
    IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?$') OR TO_NUMBER(value) < 10000 OR TO_NUMBER(value) > 7200000 THEN
        ip_msg(6214,option_name);
        RETURN;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

I am not altogether certain that would handle all values so you may want to add an `EXCEPTION` block or write a custom `to_number()` function as @JustinCave suggests.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will match numbers like 5 , -5, +5, 5.44, 3.45e-3

```
REGEXP_LIKE('54.55e33', '^[+-]?\d+([.]\d+)?(e[+-]?\d+)?$')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_NUMERIC(P_INPUT IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER IS
  RESULT INTEGER;
  NUM NUMBER ;
BEGIN
  NUM:=TO_NUMBER(P_INPUT);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RETURN 0;
END IS_NUMERIC;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DECODE(REGEXP_COUNT(:value,'\d'),LENGTH(:value),'Y','N') AS is_numeric FROM dual;
```

There are many ways but this one works perfect for me.