# CAST(VARCHAR2 AS NUMERIC) with "." in the VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, varchar2

I have a problem when converting `VARCHAR2` to `Number` in Oracle SQL.

My `VARCHAR2` has the following characteristic: 0.000

For example: the value of `Campo1` is `18.123` (with a `.`)

But I get an error:

> 1722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

when trying to convert:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Campo1 AS NUMERIC)) AS VOLUME
FROM TESTE_NUMBER
WHERE Timestamp = '18/09/2020'
```

Is it possible to convert that string?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to use [to_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm)?

Comment: Yes, @JeffreyDrake. But the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can check that it looks like a number, first.  For a non-negative:

```
select sum(case when regexp_like(campo1, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$')
                the to_number(campo1)
           end)
```

Comment: I would use [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886915/5070879) here :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you remove space:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Campo1, ' ') AS NUMERIC)) AS VOLUME
FROM TESTE_NUMBER
where Timestamp = '18/09/2020';
```

'1722. 0000' should be '1722.0000'.

---

Using safe conversion [“Safe” TO_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486949/safe-to-number/45886745#45886745) will default faulty values to 0:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Campo1 AS NUMERIC DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR)) AS VOLUME
FROM TESTE_NUMBER
where Timestamp = '18/09/2020';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e418725e79df94c7f7276a5932c6312d)**

Comment: Thanks for answering me, Lukasz. But continues with the same error inserting the select that you wrote :/