# How to change column data type which column is not empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 48'000 rows table which I import from Excel into an Oracle SQL database. In the table, there is a column named total price. This column's data type is `varchar2`, but I want to change it to `number`.

With this code

```
alter table pizza_db
modify (total_price number);
```

I get this error

> Column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Then I tried like this:

```
Alter table pizza_db 
add (total_price_num number)

update pizza_db 
set total_price_num = to_number(total_price)
```

I got this error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably the idea of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9771393/3604523) will help you to find the data that is not a number.

Comment: On 12.2 and higher, check the VALIDATE_CONVERSION function to validate numbers

Comment: After you find the non-numeric value(s) and address those, the most efficient way to convert a varchar2 column to a number column is to CTAS (`create table as select`) the data out to temp table, truncate the main table, change the datatype, then insert (with append hint) the data back in. It can be done with even less data movement if you simply rename the temp table to become your main table, but that may require more DDL work to get constraints, grants, indexes, etc. in place so the double movement is often worth the reduction of complexity. I don't recommend adding/dropping columns.

Comment: Also check your NLS settings: when numbers come as text from software like Excel, it's the most common source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `TO_NUMBER( ... DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR ... )` and can use `COALESCE` if you want to try different number formats:

```sql
ALTER TABLE pizza_db ADD (total_price_num NUMBER);

UPDATE pizza_db 
SET total_price_num = COALESCE(
                        TO_NUMBER(
                          total_price DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
                          '999999D99'
                        ),
                        TO_NUMBER(
                          total_price DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
                          'L999G999D99'
                        )
                      );
```

Which, for setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pizza_db (id, total_price) AS
SELECT 1, '12.99' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1.00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '$25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '$1,234.56' FROM DUAL;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Mexico'
```

Then after the `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM pizza_db;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TOTAL_PRICE | TOTAL_PRICE_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.99 | 12.99 |
| 2 | 1.00 | 1 |
| 3 | $25 | 25 |
| 4 | $1,234.56 | 1234.56 |

If you want to know what you have not converted you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   pizza_db
WHERE  total_price IS NOT NULL
AND    total_price_num IS NULL;
```

If you have converted all the values then you can drop the `TOTAL_PRICE` column and rename `TOTAL_PRICE_NUM` to `TOTAL_PRICE`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fRUysHiv)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following steps:

1. Add a new column to the table of data type  NUMBER.
2. Update a new column having a value from a VARCHAR2 column(assuming it has only Numeric values).
3. Drop the VARCHAR2 column.
4. Rename the newly added column.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE pizza_db(id NUMBER,  location VARCHAR2(200), total_price VARCHAR2(100));

    INSERT INTO pizza_db VALUES (1,'This is xxx',100);
    INSERT INTO pizza_db VALUES (2,'This is yyy',200);
    INSERT INTO pizza_db VALUES (3,'This is zzz',300);
    COMMIT;
   ```

ALTER TABLE pizza_db MODIFY (total_price NUMBER)
-- ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype

Steps:

```
ALTER TABLE pizza_db ADD total_price_new NUMBER;

UPDATE pizza_db SET total_price_new=total_price;
COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE pizza_db DROP COLUMN total_price;

ALTER TABLE pizza_db RENAME COLUMN total_price_new TO total_price;
    
DESC pizza_db;
  
Name        Null? Type          
----------- ----- ------------- 
ID                NUMBER        
LOCATION          VARCHAR2(500) 
TOTAL_PRICE       NUMBER
```