# Oracle SQL Developer:How do I select entries in a data based on the nature of entries in a particular column.The entries are of two different formats

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I have the following table:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| John | 12345678 |
| Jim | 23456789 |
| Alice | 34567890 |
| Eric | 234/15 |
| Joe | 13/786 |

The datatype of the ID column is varchar(255). As you can see, there are two formats for the ID:
an eight digit numeric one and one where the ID is of the format xx/xxx or xxx/xx.

I want to separate out the entries which have ID in thee eight digit numeric format. How should I structure my WHERE clause?

Comment: Perhaps something like this, using REGEXP_LIKE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932230/oracle-sql-query-that-returns-rows-with-only-numeric-values

Answer (score 0):

There are *zillion* options, you just have to pick one you find the most appropriate. Here are just some of them.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

NAME  ID
----- --------
John  12345678
Jim   23456789
Alice 34567890
Eric  234/15
Joe   13/786
```

---

ID length:

```
SQL> select name, id,
  2    case when length(id) = 8 then 'digit'
  3         else 'xxx'
  4    end what
  5  from test;

NAME  ID       WHAT
----- -------- -----
John  12345678 digit
Jim   23456789 digit
Alice 34567890 digit
Eric  234/15   xxx
Joe   13/786   xxx
```

---

Does the ID contain slash?

```
SQL> select name, id,
  2    case when instr(id, '/') = 0 then 'digit'
  3         else 'xxx'
  4    end what
  5  from test;

NAME  ID       WHAT
----- -------- -----
John  12345678 digit
Jim   23456789 digit
Alice 34567890 digit
Eric  234/15   xxx
Joe   13/786   xxx
```

---

Regular expressions: is the ID *all digits*?

```
SQL> select name, id,
  2    case when regexp_like(id, '^\d+$') then 'digit'
  3         else 'xxx'
  4    end what
  5  from test;

NAME  ID       WHAT
----- -------- -----
John  12345678 digit
Jim   23456789 digit
Alice 34567890 digit
Eric  234/15   xxx
Joe   13/786   xxx
```